# should I inject repository class or model class in controller's constructor?

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have a PostController controller and I have A post model. Here are following scenarios how I can write my code.

1. I can have a constructor in a controller and inject Post model there. like this:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    $post;
    public function __construct(Post $post){
        $this->post = $post;
    }

    public function show($id){
        return $this->post->find($id);
    }
```

2. I can directly write Post model in a function (show function).

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
   

    public function show($id){
        return Post::find($id);
    }
```

3. I can have a repository class which extends my Eloquent Post Model and inject it into constructor.

```
class PostRepository extends Post{


}

class PostController extends Controller{

    protected $post;
    public function __construct(PostRepository $post){
        $this->postRepo = $post;
    }

    public function show($id){
        return $this->postRepo->find($id);
    }
}
```

4. I can have postRepository without injecting and directly using it.

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
   

    public function show($id){
        return PostRepository::find($id);
    }
```

Let's talk about my question and how I look at it. Before I start talking, I want you to know that I want my code to be testable and well-written.

Question 1) let's say I use the second example. I'm directly accessing Post model there. It's testable because Laravel provides a way to mock Eloquent models. Why is this bad approach? I know it's bad, i just don't know why, because I can still mock Eloquent and test it.

Question 2) What's the difference between the second and the first example? If I can test it and mock an Eloquent model if it's directly accessed in a function, why to inject it in a constructor at all?

Question 3) Let's say I don't use repository patterns. Creating repository classes doesn't mean using repository pattern. Repository pattern is when used interfaces and you can swap (for example from Eloquent to other ORM). Let's say I always know that I will use only Eloquent and I don't want to decouple my code from framework itself. Then the question is why to use Repository Classes at all as shown in the third and fourth example? I'm asking this because people say that it's better to put complex logic in repositories and not in a model.

Question 4) What's the difference between the third and fourth example? I can still test the fourth example. why to inject PostRepository in a constructor at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Question 1) let's say I use the second example. I'm directly accessing
>   Post model there. It's testable because laravel provides a way to mock
>   eloquent models. Why is this bad approach? I know it's bad, i just
>   don't know why, because I can still mock eloquent and test it.

It's only bad if you have a large app with a need to swap out the storage layer. If you're never going to change the storage layer from DB to something else, it's not a bad approach at all and it is totally testable.

> Question 2) What's the difference between the second and the first
>   example? If I can test it and mock an eloquent model if it's directly
>   accessed in a function, why to inject it in a constructor at all?

There is no difference between the 2nd and 1st example. That's because the repository implementation is incorrect. It should not extend the Post class. It should in fact implement an interface with select methods like so:

```
class PostDatabaseRepository extends PostRepositoryContract {
    public function show($id){
        return Post::find($id)->toArray();
    }

...
}
```

Then, in your service provider bind the contract to the database repository like so:

```
$this->app->singleton(
    PostRepositoryContract::class, PostDatabaseRepository::class
);
```

This way if you want to swap out the implementation, just change the binding as above.

> Question 3) Let's say I don't use repository patterns. Creating
>   repository classes doesn't mean using repository pattern. Repository
>   pattern is when used interfaces and you can swap (for example from
>   eloquent to other ORM). Let's say I always know that I will use only
>   eloquent and I don't want to decouple my code from framework itself.
>   Then the question is why to use Repository Classes at all as shown in
>   the third and fourth example? I'm asking this because people say that
>   it's better to put complex logic in repositories and not in a model.

If you know that you'll only use Eloquent, you should not use the Repository pattern.

> Question 4) What's the difference between the third and fourth
>   example? I can still test the fourth example. why to inject
>   PostRepository in a constructor at all?

Your example's implementation is incorrect. You should not add the concrete class in the constructor for dependency injection. Instead, you should add the interface like so:

```
public function __construct(PostRepositoryContract $post){
    $this->postRepo = $post;
}
```

This way you can swap out implementations without needing to change the above code.

Also, as @Polaris mentioned in the comments, you should not return the data as a collection or eloquent model. Otherwise it defeats the whole purpose of using the Repository pattern. Return an array or perhaps a separate Post class (non Eloquent and not specific to an implementation).

Comment: Well put, upvoted. I would just like to add that if you do decide to use the Repository pattern, you should return the data as an array and not a collection or eloquent model. Otherwise it defeats the whole purpose of using the Repository pattern.

Comment: I agree @Polaris, have changed the implementation to return an array. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. I think your second answer is wrong, because my second question was something else. also I have seen that people inject repositories (not interfaces) in constructor. because they don't want repository pattern(to swap implementations) but they want to have functions (huge complex functions) to be in a repository and not in a model directly.

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili injecting specific implementations in constructors defeats the purpose of the repository pattern and is a bad practice. People who do that are simply doing it wrong. You will never see that in any good framework or package.

Comment: I'm not saying that passing repository class in a constructor is a repository pattern. I know what repository pattern is. I just saw examples where people pass specific repository classes to constructors , because they don't want to write big,huge logic in a controller or in a model. do you understand?

Comment: Yes, I understand but that doesnt make any sense. They are writing database specific logic in a separate repository class and then also writing database specific logic in a model. That's violating several SOLID principles and is a bad practice.

Comment: So imagine there's no way you ever need to change from eloquent to other ORM.  then this way you're using models directly in a constructor. Let's say in a controller called PostController and in its method called store , there's a super huge business logic code which might be needed in some other controller. where would you write this piece of code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184232/discussion-between-nika-khurashvili-and-paras).

Comment: If it's business specific logic, you can extract it in a separate service class as long as it doesnt have query/DB logic (that's the responsibility of the model).

Comment: Yes, you inject an interface into the controller and bind the interface to an implementation with app()->bind() in Laravel. That way, all you need to do is swap out the binding to change database layers.